# How to display an array of objects derived from a base class, each with it's own different operator overload function?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

So i have a base class, and 3 derived classes, and another class template which as a parameter is given the base class, class template has an array of the 3 different type of objects.  I have overloaded the << operator for all 3 derived classes and the base class, but when i try to display all the array in the console, the base class operator overload function is used, how do i make it in such a way that when i iterate through the array of objects and display each one, it's different for every type of object?

base class representation

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Sushi
{
private:
    static int count;
protected:
    int id;
    int cost;
    std::string fish_type;
public:
    Sushi();
    Sushi(int cost, std::string fish_type);
    ~Sushi();

    int get_id();
    int get_cost();
    std::string get_ftype();

    void set_cost(int cost);
    void set_ftype(std::string fish);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Sushi& sushi);
};
```

base class operator

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Sushi& sushi)
{
    os << sushi.id << " " << sushi.cost << " " << sushi.fish_type << std::endl;
    return os;
}
```

class template representation

```
#pragma once
#include "Sushi.h"
template <class Sushi>
class SushiRepository
{
    Sushi *repo;
    int capacity;
    int top;

public:
    //default constructor
    SushiRepository();
    
    //constructor
    SushiRepository(int size);

    //adds an element to top of the stack
    void push(Sushi s);

    //Pops an element from the top of the stack and returns it
    Sushi pop();

    //Returns the last element from the top of the stack
    Sushi peek();

    //returns the size of the repo
    int size();

    //checks if repo is empty
    bool isEmpty();

    //checks if repo is full
    bool isFull();

    //remove by id
    void removeByID(int id);

    //display all
    void displayAll();

    ~SushiRepository();
};
```

class template display function

```
template <class Sushi>
inline void SushiRepository<Sushi>::displayAll()
{
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << repo[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Repo is empty";
    }
}

template<class Sushi>
SushiRepository<Sushi>::~SushiRepository()
{
    delete[] repo;
}
```

derived class representation

```
#pragma once
#include "Sushi.h"
#include <ostream>
class Sashimi : public Sushi
{
    std::string bed;

public:
    Sashimi();
    Sashimi(std::string bed);
    ~Sashimi();

    std::string get_bed();
    void set_bed(std::string b);
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Sashimi &sh);
};
```

one of the derived classes operator overload function

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Sashimi& sh)
{
    os << "ID:" << sh.id << " Sashimi of " << sh.fish_type << " on a bed of: " << sh.bed << " cost: " << sh.cost << std::endl;
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Please don't describe your code, *show* it to us. [Edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: First of all you haven't shown how e.g. `Sashimi` and `Sushi` are related. There could also be some misunderstandings because you have the `Sushi` class, and the `Sushi` template argument for `SushiRepository`, and those two types might not be the same. Furthermore you seem to have three *different* containers for sushi, and none of the three specific instantiations will be related to each other, i.e. there no generic `SushiRepository` for `Sushi`. I also recommend you use `std::vector` to store the objects so you don't have to create your own memory handling.

Comment: [Continued] And for polymorphism to work properly you need *pointers*. Pointers to the base class to be more specific, and initialize them using pointers to the child classes. Then you also don't need a template repository, but it will work with a single non-template `SushiRepository` class containing a `std::vector<Sushi*>`. At least if you want to collect all different sushi's in a single repository.

Comment: [Continued] Lastly about the output... If you use inheritance and polymorphism correctly, then you should not use different `operator<<` overloads for each of the child-classes. Only have a single `operator<<(std::ostream&, Sushi const&)` operator function, which calls a polymorphic (i.e. `virtual`) protected member function `output(std::ostream&)` function to handle the specific output for the child class.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i'll try using the std::vector, thank you for the clarification of my code

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i have one small question, we might not be allowed to use std::vector since this is a school assignment, is it still possible to do it even without it?

Comment: Your description of (what I assume is) `SushiRepository` does not seem to agree with your code that uses it. How is it defined?

Comment: @molbdnilo i added the representation of the repository, in case you ask why i don't use the std::stack<sushi>, its for a school assignment, can't use that

Comment: So `SushiRepository` actually has *one* array, of whatever type is provided as the template argument. (You are aware that the `Sushi` in that template has no relation to the `Sushi` class, right? It's not clear why that is a template at all.) You probably want to read some more about polymorphism and the problems of object slicing in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: You need (1) pointers/references and (2) virtual functions. Inheritance in C++ doesn't really work without these two things. Any book or tutorial or course that doesn't mention this is very suspect.

Comment: @molbdnilo i wasn't aware that they have no relation, thank you for the clarification